# Running a Powershell Script on Windows Service Failure. Works when run manually but not when service fails. Advice needed

Tags: windows, powershell, email

So I have been working on a script to essentially send an email when a Service fails. The script works just fine, as I've run it manually from PowerShell. I get the email and everything checks out.
I then add this to the service:
[Service Recovery Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYHbM.png)

I tell it to run Powershell by linking to the executable:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

And the execute the following script:

```
-command C:\Users\andreand\Desktop\Sendmail.ps1
```

As mentioned, I tried this manually in PowerShell, and I got an error. If I append the PowerShell location before the -command it works. Like so:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command C:\Users\andreand\Desktop\Sendmail.ps1
```

So this works if I run it manually, but when the service fails, nothing happens.
I trigger a failure by doing `/taskkill /F /PID pid`, and I can see the service has stopped.

What am I missing? I feel like I am so close and it is frustrating!

Comment: Check the System event log to see if your recovery script was executed. I'd also assume the script runs as the user context of the service so you might need to check whether that user can run the script successfully.

Comment: Right just did this. An Error does come up saying the Service terminated unexpectedly and tat "The corrective action will be taken in 0 milliseconds; Run the configured recovery program". Looking at the Powershell tab of the Event Viewer I can see that Powershell also seem to be starting. I have set the Execution Policy in PowerShell to RemoteSigned, so the script should definitely be able to run.

Comment: Sounds like it is attempting to execute it then. Have you checked if its a user context issue?

Comment: Also try changing the command line parameters to this: `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command C:\Users\andreand\Desktop\Sendmail.ps1`. My theory being the user that the service/script runs at has execution policy set to restricted, where as that is not an issue when you run it manually.

Comment: Should I stick this in the Command Line Parameter field or is this something I just run once on the machine in question using PowerShell?

Comment: Put it in the Command Line Parameter field as it will then change the execution policy temporarily just for this invocation of PowerShell and you won't have to worry about the machine level config being changed in the future.

Comment: No luck. The service definitely fails, but I'm still not getting an email when it does.

Comment: Add `Start-Transcript -Path C:\Temp\Transcript.txt` at the top of your script and `Stop-Transcript` at the bottom. Then kill the service and check the transcript file to see what errors might be occurring.

Comment: Right definitely getting some errors. I'm new on StackOverflow, would you be able to start a chat and I can send over the transcript. Might be a bit long for a comment?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148295/running-a-powershell-script-on-windows-service-failure-works-when-run-manually-b

Comment: You might have a problem because you've encrypted the string with one user account, but then are trying to decrypt it with another. PowerShell encryption for secure strings is linked to the user that performed the encryption.

Comment: I see. Is there any easy way around this? If possible I would rather have added password protection so it's not just floating around.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Wragg here suggested, the problem lies in that I encrypted the string with one user account, but trying to decrypt it with another. By not using encryption for the password, it works.

I am still trying to figure out if there is any way to keep the encryption and have this work.

Furthermore, I am now trying to embed the failed service in the email subject field, but I am unsure how to do this. I have seen the Get-Service Cmdlet, but that seems to fetch an entire list, where I would just need it to read back the service that failed. Any help on this is most welcome.

EDIT: I have now found solutions to both encrypting the password and retrieving a list of services.
To encrypt the password, I used an encryption key. It goes something like this:

```
# Change this location as necessary.
PS C:\Users\andreand> $File = 'C:\SomeLocation\Key.txt'

PS C:\Users\andreand> [Byte[]] $Key = (1..16)

# The password for the mail account / SMTP client.
PS C:\Users\andreand> $Password = 'Passwordgoeshere' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

PS C:\Users\andreand> $Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $Key | Out-File 
$File
```

After this, I input the following into my script to retrieve the encrypted key:

```
$File = 'C:\SomeLocation\Key.txt'
[Byte[]] $Key = (1..16)
$Password = Get-Content $File | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $Key
```

For retrieving the list of services, I used the Get-Service cmdlet, but with some filtering to find the services I wanted. Like so:

```
$Services = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "ServiceName*"}
```